# Separar en funciones, años bisiestos

Tags: vs

Tengo que hacer un programa en C, visual studio 2019 que calcule los años bisiestos entre dos años ingresados, ya medio tengo el codigo hecho pero hay  cosas que no se como hacerlas, tengo que hacer el codigo en cuatro funciones y no se como separarlo. Tambien tengo que hacer que los años aparezcan como lista y esa debe ser una funcion que el usuario debe responder. Aqui agrego el codigo que tengo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int esBisiesto(int anno)
    {
        return anno % 4 == 0 && (anno % 100 != 0 || anno % 400 == 0);
    }

    int main()
    {
       int annoInicial;
       int annoFinal;

       printf("Programa que encuentra los años bisiestos");
       printf("que existen entre dos años ingresados");

       printf("Primer año:");
       scanf_s("%d", &annoInicial);

       printf("Segundo año:");
       scanf_s("%d", &annoFinal);

    while (annoInicial <= annoFinal)
    {
        if (esBisiesto(annoInicial))
        {
            printf("Años bisiestos:", esBisiesto);
        }

        annoInicial++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dhani, recuerdo q hace un tiempo te ayude en esa pregunta y te explique que las variables no pueden ser float sino enteros, por tanto tu scanf debe ser modificado para que acepte numeros enteros

Comment: si recurdo, pero no se como hacer que lea los datos enteros, le cambie la f por d (creo que era esa, perdon si me equivoco), pero aun me marca error, me aparece : "printf": se pasaron demasiados argumentos para la cadena de formato, los marcadores de posición y sus parámetros esperan 0 argumentos variádicos, pero se proporcionaron 1, error de sintaxis: ')'

Comment: Oh disculpe no me habia dado cuenta, ya lo cambie, es C

Comment: Ya te respondieron esto en tu pregunta anterior.. aca estas pidiendo que te hagan el ejercicio completo? no entiendo el sentido de esta pregunta, comparandola con la anterior....

Comment: Dhani dejemoslo para manana q ya es tarde

Comment: Y otra cosa.. visual studio 2019 es tu ide.. no estas haciendo un programa en vs 2019.. estas haciendo un programa en C.. si queres, usando como IDE vs2019 (esto lo recalco para que aprendas)...

Comment: Dhani aun no tienes suficiente puntuacion para acceder al chat debes tener 20ptos

Comment: manana vemos q hacemos dani

Comment: Pero recuerda dani debes esforzarte e investigar recuerda q la tarea es tuya, q te lo haga otro no vale

Comment: Muchas gracias por corregirme con mis errores, y una disculpa que moleste con la tarea, es que sinceramente nos es mi fuerte programación y mucho menos con las clases en linea, me disculpo nuevamenete por las molestias